# Navbar not hiding in Drawer in ''react-native-router-flux"

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to hide the default navbar by `react-native-router-flux`. I have disabled the `navBar`. But stilled It is showing it.

Here is My code Below

```
import { Router, Scene, Stack, Drawer } from "react-native-router-flux"
```

.
.
.

```
<Drawer
          hideNavBar={true}
          key="drawer"
          contentComponent={DrawerContent}
          drawerPosition="left"
          drawerWidth={200}>
            <Scene key="calendar" component={Calendar}/>
</Drawer>
```

Output right now:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Trying also putting the hidenav bar prop on the specific scene. Could also be a issue with your padding.

Comment: I used Scene as drawer to hide the navbar instead of using drawer. It is working now